# How to call post title and post summary to other part of site?

Tags: php, posts

My blog is installed at `/posts` of my site.

It's not a mistake; I wanted to be like that. But now my homepage looks somewhat empty. Here I want to call the title of my blog to my homepage, with a link to the original post at `/posts`, followed by a summary of the post.

I don't know where to start; I actually have no any technical understanding of WordPress and how it works.

My blog is currently installed at http://sntsh.com/posts/.

Comment: What did you do to install your blog at `/posts`? There are many ways to do this but I suspect you created a page and set it as a posts page in the reading settings - is that correct?

Comment: I installed WordPress via Softaculous.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that software. Did you install the complete site in a subdirectory?

Comment: Ya, You got it right!

Comment: In that case just follow these instructions:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory#Using_a_pre-existing_subdirectory_install

Comment: You can then display a static front page at your sntsh.com and your blog post overview at sntsh.com/posts **or** the blog post overview at sntsh.com. This is explained here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page

Comment: You didn't actually get my problem. I don't want to shift my installation to root of my site. I just want some posts (just title and summary of) to the homepage.

Comment: Glad you found the answer yourself, I was disconnected from the internet and couldn't get back earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two methods:

The one mentioned in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9224280/939986).

And the one mentioned in this [Codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website).